# Corona - can't save event.alert to GGData

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am using GGData from here ([GGData](https://github.com/GlitchGames/GGData)). It work like a charm. Until I want to save `event.alert` that I receive from `notificationListener`. It is strange that, when i popup the event like this `native.showAlert("Title",event.alert,{"Ok"})`. It will display event.alert message. But when I try to save it to GGData like this :

```
local function notificationListener( event )
    -- display alert that shows the event name and type:
    print("init notificationListener")

    local yo = GGData:new("tuohai")
    yo:set("message",event.alert)
    yo:save()
end
```

It doesn't get the value of event.alert. Why is that happening?

Comment: Just to quickly rule out the most common mistakes, did you remember to add "local GGData = require( "GGData" )"? And could you try to use this "yo:set("message", ""..event.alert)"

Comment: already declare `local GGData = require("GGData")` but i not yet trying `yo.set("message","..event.alert..")` that seem to give some hope. gonna try it now.

Comment: i got error when doing this `yo:set("message", ""..event.alert)` which is `attempt to concatenate field 'alert' (a nil value)`

Comment: Hmm, that means event.alert = nil - which it shouldn't be. Could you show the place where you declare the listener?